# Constructing a path with the format operator throws a type error

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the builtin `-f` feature of PowerShell, but I keep getting hit with an error of

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.

Here is my code, what am I doing incorrectly to be able to do what I am wanting to do?

```
$beefcakes = @('Homeboy', 'Coldfry', 'Redpearl')
foreach ($bf in $beefcakes) {
  $HomeDir = "C:\Testing\"
  $DestPath = "$HomeDir\$bf\"
  switch ($bf) {
    Homeboy  { $redfern = "1234" }
    Coldfry  { $redfern = "888" }
    Redpearl { $redfern = "0011" }
  }

  if (Test-Path '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf) {
    $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
  } else {
    $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}_Redo.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the formatting expression in a subexpression or assign it to a variable, otherwise PowerShell will interpret the `-f` as the abbreviated parameter `-Filter` for [`Test-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx), which expects a string argument, not an object array.

```
Test-Path       '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f      $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
    ⇕                  ⇕           ⇕                 ⇕
Test-Path -Path '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -Filter $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
```

Change this:

```
if (Test-Path '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf) {
  $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
} else {
  $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}_Redo.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
}
```

into either this:

```
if (Test-Path ('{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf)) {
  $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
} else {
  $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}_Redo.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
}
```

or (better) this:

```
$savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
if (-not (Test-Path $savefile)) {
  $savefile = '{0}\{1}_{2}_Redo.csv' -f $DestPath, $redfern, $bf
}
```

---

On a more general note, it's good practice to avoid repeated assignment of static values inside loops (`$HomeDir`), and it's also good practice to use the [`Join-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) cmdlet for building paths (saves you the headache of having to manage backslashes). You don't even need the format operator here. Simply put your variables in double-quoted strings.

```
$HomeDir = 'C:\Testing'
foreach ($bf in $beefcakes) {
  $DestPath = Join-Path $HomeDir $bf
  ...
  $basename = "${redfern}_${bf}"
  $savefile = Join-Path $DestPath "$basename.csv"
  if (-not (Test-Path $savefile)) {
    $savefile = Join-Path $DestPath "${basename}_Redo.csv"
  }
}
```